# Is ASP.Net Web API a good choice for API consumed by .Net and PHP?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

In the old days, I used ASMX which provides strongly typed classes via SOAP WSDL.

I have to implement API which will be consumed by both .Net and PHP. So I already decided to go with REST (I'm really impressed by the Azure's Rest APIs such as Blob storage).

I'm pretty new to Web API although I read few books - [Pro ASP.NET MVC 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430242361), [APIs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449308929), [Pro ASP.NET Web API Security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430257822). However, I still can't figure out the followings -

### Questions

1. Can a client get strongly typed classes from Web API like SOAP WSDL? (If not, what do I have to do in order to get a strong typed classes like Azure Blob Storage)
2. Can PHP client consume Web API easily? *(I know nothing about PHP)*

Thank you for shedding a light!

*Please note that this is not an argument about SOAP vs Rest, [Web API vs WCF](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/207239/how-do-i-manage-the-technical-debate-over-wcf-vs-web-api).*

Comment: Anything that is standards compliant be it a SOAP interface or restful or just simple XML feeds or database driven direct web services (ie: out of sql server) will do exactly what you want as long as they're standards compliant then any language will support consumption

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) On the client side you can parse the response (json/xml) as your strongly-typed class. Code snippet from [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client):

You have already defined Product class in your client:

```
class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

Then you call the API to get products and get the response parsed into enumerable of Products:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/products").Result;  // Blocking call!
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // Parse the response body. Blocking!
    var products = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Product>>().Result;
    foreach (var p in products)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1};\t{2}", p.Name, p.Price, p.Category);
    }
}
```

2) ASP .NET Web API is based on HTTP. So as long as your client talks HTTP you can consume the web services.